# Has docker support of locate/grep commands?

Tags: docker

If docker has support of commands which I use in ubuntu :

```
locate filename
```

and

```
grep -Hrn  -A 5 'search text' --include="*.php"  /DirectoryPath/
```

If yes, how can I install them ?

**UPDATED # 2 :**
After adding command in my Dockerfile.yml

```
RUN apt-get install -y grep mlocate
```

I can run command :

```
grep -Hrn  -A 5 'var' --include="*.conf"  /var/www
```

with valid results, but errors with locate :

```
root@11ed27f97ac4:/var/www# locate -help
Usage: locate [OPTION]... [PATTERN]...
Search for entries in a mlocate database.

  -A, --all              only print entries that match all patterns
  -b, --basename         match only the base name of path names
  -c, --count            only print number of found entries
  -d, --database DBPATH  use DBPATH instead of default database (which is
                         /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db)
  -e, --existing         only print entries for currently existing files
  -L, --follow           follow trailing symbolic links when checking file
                         existence (default)
  -h, --help             print this help
  -i, --ignore-case      ignore case distinctions when matching patterns
  -l, --limit, -n LIMIT  limit output (or counting) to LIMIT entries
  -m, --mmap             ignored, for backward compatibility
  -P, --nofollow, -H     don't follow trailing symbolic links when checking file
                         existence
  -0, --null             separate entries with NUL on output
  -S, --statistics       don't search for entries, print statistics about each
                         used database
  -q, --quiet            report no error messages about reading databases
  -r, --regexp REGEXP    search for basic regexp REGEXP instead of patterns
      --regex            patterns are extended regexps
  -s, --stdio            ignored, for backward compatibility
  -V, --version          print version information
  -w, --wholename        match whole path name (default)

Report bugs to mitr@redhat.com.
root@11d2e77af9c4:/var/www# mlocate -i error.log 
mlocate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
```

Why error at last line ? Seems I use valid syntax ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried? What happens if you did?

Comment: Docker on its own doesn't support any commands at all; you can build a custom image `FROM scratch` and that won't have anything, not even a shell.  But if you build an image `FROM ubuntu` then it's likely to have these sorts of commands in it.  Especially grep(1) is a very standard command and included in BusyBox (though not with the GNU extensions) and should be available in most images that have any sort of Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your docker file you have to add the following command:

```
RUN apt install -y grep mlocate
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Dockerfile before running locate

```
RUN /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining what the mentioned command is doing and how it solves the problem.